# Reading / Using files in the server /home/ folder

Tags: php, home-directory

I have 7 different custom websites, all on the same server, that use the same config and image files.  I would like to reference those files by "including" using PHP, or referencing them as src images.  Unfortunately, when I try to pull the resources, I get errors.  Is there a way to use these files directly from the /home/ directory so that a single change there is seen on all websites?  Here is what I am using now that isn't working:

```
 <?php include("/home/config.php"); ?>
```

and

```
<img style="vertical-align:bottom" src="/home/buy_button.png" border="0" />
```

Comment: do you use virtual hosting for the 7 websites?

Comment: do you use apache2? php as apache module or fcgi? Need more information! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple questions here:

1 . How can I make PHP include these files. ?

> Make sure the webserver user e.g. www-data on ubuntu has proper permissions to access those files.
> I would suggest something different from /home/.. (if you ask me)

2 . How to access those image files from web?

> If you are using apache you'll have to create an alias that makes that images accessible via the web server.

Here comes an example for apache2

```
Alias /img /home/path/to/images
<Directory "/home/path/to/images">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Place this configuration snippet in the proper place of your apache installation e.g. end of httpd.conf or a separate file. Don't forget to restart your webserver.

Now you should be able to access the images like:

```
<img style="vertical-align:bottom" src="http://www.myserver.com/img/buy_button.png"border="0" />
```