# Display image on web which is located in home directory

Tags: image, tomcat, spring-mvc, nginx, upload

My project is in Spring MVC, and  runs tomcat7 and nginx. 
I upload all multimedia which are added by users into /home/multimedia.

I want to show multimedia to users from there. How can I do?

I find a solution for PHP, but it doesn't answer my question.

[Reading / Using files in the server /home/ folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076613/reading-using-files-in-the-server-home-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go two routes. The first has the least overhead. The second is more convenient if there is a need for configurable locations.

### 1. Serve static files using Nginx

Create a alias to the target directory.

```
location /media {
    alias /home/multimedia;
    expires 1y;
}
```

### 2. Serve static files using Spring MVC

You can configure static resources with Spring MVC that point to that directory on the filesystem.

Using Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/media/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/home/multimedia/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
}
```

Or XML configuration in e.g. **dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<mvc:resources location="file:/home/multimedia" mapping="/media/**" cache-period="31556926" />
```

Comment: Is it enough to create a class which is named ServletConfig and past these code?

Comment: No it depends on whether you have a Java or XML based configuration. The above class is part of the former. I added the XML configuration of resources to the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Code to read image from disk and save in BufferedImage using core java

```
public BufferedImage savetiff(File srcFilePath) throws IOException {
        FileSeekableStream stream = new FileSeekableStream(srcFilePath);
        TIFFDecodeParam decodeParam = new TIFFDecodeParam();

        decodeParam.setDecodePaletteAsShorts(true);
        ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();

        params.add(stream);
        RenderedOp image1 = JAI.create("tiff", params);
        BufferedImage img = image1.getAsBufferedImage();

        return img;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution for this question.

Comment: @egemen php link you provided was to read image so I gave you this code.`<img style="vertical-align:bottom" src="/home/buy_button.png" border="0" />` if you want to do this than in src call you controller class and return type of which should be image. I have done this using servlet for captacha image.